# Create multiple Data Frames and columns with loops

Tags: r, date, weather

Thanks in advance for your help, im really struggeling here.
lets jump right in.

### WHAT I HAVE SO FAR

Currently i have Weather Data to use with DSSAT (= a crop growth simulation model). Its name is REPY0001.WTH.
It looks like this:

**Weather Data for DSSAT:**

[image: Weather Data for DSSAT]

I managed to load it into R with the following command:

```
temp0 <- read.csv("Data/Wetterdaten/REPY0001.WTH", sep = "", header = FALSE)
```

Then it looks in R Like this:

**REPY0001.WTH in RStudio:**

[image: REPY0001.WTH in RStudio]

i have already exported it from RStudio and used it in DSSAT, which works when i use 3x white spaces as seperator's with the following command:

```
write.table(temp,file = "Data/Wetterdaten/test6.WTH", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, sep = "   ")
```

With 1 or 2 white spaces as seperator's DSSAT was not able to read it properly. I Assume there are hard restrictions how the Files should look like so DSSAT can read them.

### WHAT I WANT TO HAVE AS A RESULT

In the End i want to have **99 Output Files** from REPY0001.WTH to REPY9901.WTH.
In this Files the First Column Starting in Row 5 needs to change/match with the Numbers in the Filename.

So The File REPY**50**01.WTH needs to have this Structure:

> *WEATHER DATA : REPY
>
> @ INSI      LAT     LONG  ELEV   TAV   AMP REFHT WNDHT   REPY   52.190
> 8.195   300   9.4   8.1 -99.0 -99.0 @DATE  SRAD  TMAX  TMIN  RAIN  DEWP  WIND   PAR  EVAP  RHUM
> **50**225  18.2  29.0  16.3   0.0
> **50**226  15.5  24.2  14.0   0.0
> **50**227  22.1  25.1  12.6   0.0
> **50**228  22.0  24.1  10.4   0.0
>
> but after **50**365 the Day of The Year 365 is reached and the next column needs to be
>
> **51**001 ... since it has changed from Year 50 to 51.

and in File REPY**51**01.WTH the @DATE column needs to start with **51**225 ...
(It stands for last two digits of the Year, So Year 1956 is -> REPY**56** and @DATE **56**225, ...)

In the 2nd step i want to change the value of one column in the 99 Output Files. The first Idea would be to multiply the column "Rain" with 1.0[i].
For example:

> REPY0001.WTH$Rain * 1.00
>
> REPY0101.WTH$Rain * 1.01
>
> REPY0201.WTH$Rain * 1.02
>
> REPY0301.WTH$Rain * 1.03
>
> REPY0401.WTH$Rain * 1.04
>
> ...
> So for example with every Year the Rainfall increases by 1%.

But this is really difficult right now because when i read the Files in R its a List, and when i OUTPUT the Files they need to have the correct structure for DSSAT starting with the 5 rows of the "Header".

### HOW CAN I DO THAT?

So my Question is, how i manage to get my 99 Output-Files, how i do modify the columns, and how i can do that without crashing the structure, so DSSAT can still read it afterwards.

I tried a lot of stuff but nothing worked so far.

I would be really thankfull if there is someone here that can help me find a solution.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your question according to [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and do not paste images

Comment: Thanks for your Advice. im struggling with providing the data. Since this is a list dput doesnt seem to work. I try to come up with something to maintain the structure but extract it as a dataframe.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the Dasst package? It has proper classes for this type of data, and functions that may provide the functionality you want out of the box. Package vignette (long-form documentation): https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Dasst/vignettes/aNoteOnDasst.pdf and Package Functions Documentation: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Dasst/Dasst.pdf

Comment: Thanks @csgroen. That looks promising. Im gonna try that first and see if this leads to success.